# How do I write a query to delete duplicates in a table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Given a table resembling this one, called VehicleUser:

VehicleUserId | VehicleId | UserId 
1                     | 1001       | 2 
2                     | 1001       | 2 
3                     | 1001       | 2 
4                     | 1001       | 3 
5                     | 1001       | 3 
6                     | 1001       | 3

How do I write a query that can delete the duplicates? row 2 and 3 are identical to row 1 except for a different VehicleUserId and rows 5 and 6 are identical to 4 except for a different VehicleUserId.

Comment: There are a few good answers below which will do what you're asking for, however, I would also recommend you think about what the VehicleUserId is there for.  This kind of join table looks like exactly the kind of thing where a composite primary key is appropriate, especially as you're asking how to remove these duplicates.  You might want to restructure your table to avoid having to do this in the future.

Comment: In a somewhat related side-note: this is a good example of why not all tables need an IDENTITY (or Sequence) field. In this case, the PK should be a composite of VehicleId and UserId. This would have been a cleaner data model and would have prevented the need for this question as it would be impossible to get duplicates :).

Comment: A single column is more convenient to use as a reference. For how do you know that VehicleUser cannot possibly be referenced too? But for integrity's sake there should probably be created a unique index on the pair of VehicleId & UserId.

Comment: @Andriy: that is a common mistake that people make. There is rarely a reason to abstract the UserID / VehicleID relationship via an additional meaningless IDENTITY field. By using a composite PK it both maintains the data integrity AND is what gets referenced in other tables. Foreign Keys can certainly point to composite PKs. Adding a Unique Index in this case just adds more schema and disk I/O to make up for a poor modeling decision.

Comment: @srutzky: No argue about that where 'vehicle + user' abstraction is indeed unnecessary. Yet you yourself seem to accept the fact that sometimes the abstraction *is* needed. I know of a project where such an abstraction, called 'Driver', takes place and seems relevant so far. Although now I'm starting to wonder if it wouldn't be better off without Driver...

Comment: If you're programming using an ORM or other framework that expects a single identity column per table, the single identity can be useful. It may not optimize storage, but it optimizes developer time by being consistent.

Answer (score 6):

```
;with cte as (
select row_number() over 
    (partition by VehicleId, UserId order by VehicleUserId) as rn
from VehicleUser)
delete from cte
where rn > 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

You could filter duplicates with a `exists` clause, like:

```
delete  v1
from    VehicleUser v1
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    VehicleUser v2
        where   v1.VehicleId = v2.VehicleId
                and v1.UserId = v2.UserId
                and v1.VehicleUserId > v2.VehicleUserId
        )
```

Before you run this, check if it works by replacing the `delete` with a `select`:

```
select  *
from   VehicleUser v1
where  exists
       (
       ...
```

The rows that show up will be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

here's your unique values:

```
select vehicleid, userid, min(vehicleuserid) as min_id
from vehicleuser
group by vehicleid, userid
```

you can put them in a new table before deleting anything to make sure you have what you want, then delete vehicleUser or use an outer join to delete rows from vehicleUser that aren't in the new table.

Debugging before deleting rows is safer.

Comment: Hey thanks for the `min(column)` trick - I didn't think there would be a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this purely in a single query.

I'd do a grouped query to find the duplicates, then iterate the results, deleting all but the first VehicleUserId row.

```
select VehicleId, UserId
from VehicleUser
group by VehicleId, UserId
having count(*) > 1
```

Will get you the VehicleId/UserId combinations for which there are duplicates.